# ClassCastException using Primefaces PickList

Tags: java, primefaces, classcastexception, backing-beans, picklist

I got the following DTO Object

```
public class ToManyAssociationModel<T> implements Serializable {
    private DualListModel<String> assigned;
    ...
    public ToManyAssociationModel() {
                ...
                source.add("FOO");
                source.add("BAR");
                ...
                assigned = new DualListModel<String>(source,target
                        );
        }
}
```

My frontend looks like this:

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{benutzerkontoModel.availableBenutzergruppen}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities}" itemValue="#{cities}" />
```

and the BenutzerkontoModel looks like this:

```
 public BenutzerkontoDTO(Benutzerkonto benutzerkonto, ToManyAssociationModel<Long> benutzergruppen) {
        assert benutzerkonto != null : "benutzerkonto must not be null";
        assert benutzergruppen != null : "benutzergruppen must not be null";

        this.benutzerkonto = benutzerkonto;
        this.benutzergruppen = benutzergruppen;
    }
```

However I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.primefaces.model.DualListModel to field de.db.udg.diagnose.udgdiag.domain.base.ToManyAssociationModel.assigned of type org.primefaces.model.DualListModel in instance of de.db.udg.diagnose.udgdiag.domain.base.ToManyAssociationModel
```

Domain POM (where ToManyAssociationModel is nested): (only relevant parts)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

WAR POM: (only relevant parts)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

 <!-- PrimeFaces File Upload utils -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like PF classes are loaded multiple times by different class loaders. Are there multiple occurrences of primefaces*.jar on your class path?

Comment: @Selaron I got the primefaces jar in my ear and war.
In maven I use it on 2 modules. 1 Jar and 1 war.

Comment: How do your pom.xml's look like?

Comment: @Selaron added, I'm playing around with scopes atm... but couldn't fix the `classcastexception` yet